# Constraint Layout not working properly despite adding constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using `Constraint Layout` in a list item and having difficulties in getting it to work properly when the code is compiled, though it is coming up properly in the `preview pane`. I can use `Relative Layout` but still want to know why it does not work because I am facing this problematic behaviour in many other cases.

**In the image below, this is how the layout is, with all the children 
 constrained as desired.**

[image]

**For the sake of clarity, below image shows each child's constraints individually**

[image]

**This is how it renders in a `recycler view` :**

[image]

**List item scrolled down :**

[image]

**Source code for this layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_recent_activity">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/civ_user_avatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@color/primary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/civ_user_avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_candidate_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextTitle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_candidate_email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_status"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/civ_user_avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/civ_user_avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_candidate_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextSecondary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_status"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_candidate_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_candidate_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Assessment : "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_candidate_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_candidate_email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_assessment_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextTitleBold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView7" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Is there an explanation for this behavior so that I can understand how Constraint layout is actually working?

**Update :**  After removing bottom constraints of `Imageview` and `textView7`constraint, the layout looks as below :

[image]

Comment: in `"@+id/textView7"` change `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` with any other view because it's expanding your parent view as like `match_parent` while in  actual that is `wrap_content`

Comment: set all childeren's of constraintlayou `layout_height` and `layout_width` to 0dp

Comment: @ashwin Did you get answer or it's still there ??

Comment: @Hanzala I removed bottom constraints from ImageView and `@+id/textView7`, which brought the top-most views to the right place, but the two layers below are still expanding like `match_parent`

Comment: then find more views were you added `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`  like in `civ_user_avatar`

Answer (score 5):

For all of your views instead of match_parent

**use 0dp in the xml or select fill_parent in the design view**

Comment: Doing this hides all the child views

Comment: there is no such  `match_constraint` in java android. Perhaps you meant `fill_parent`

Answer (score 1):

Please try below layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/civ_user_avatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@color/primary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/civ_user_avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_candidate_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_status"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/civ_user_avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/civ_user_avatar" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_candidate_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_status"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_candidate_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_candidate_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Assessment : "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_candidate_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_candidate_email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_assessment_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView7" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but the constraints on `tv_candidate_email` are not there which is why it went to Top-Left corner after compilation

Comment: are you hiding `tv_candidate_email` programatically ?

Comment: No, it is visible. Shifts to top-left(start) corner of the screen due to no constraints

Comment: Yeah, give me a moment

Comment: Updated the question after removing constraints to the bottom of the parent

Comment: From where this `all` Textview comes up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186838/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-ashwin-mahajan).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Guidelines, for example horizontal, and you can fit all the view more easy there. If you combine it with 2 or 3 verticals (guidelines) it will be more easy to arrive it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit as to how would it solve the problem? I have solved it by defining `chaining-type` of the view chain and giving constant height to the `Textviews`.

Comment: You can add vertical and horizontal guidelines to make it. It's not hard and easy to understand. It works with screen percentage. And you can attach the constrains to the guideline. [follow the link](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html)